# How to open a link to call or Mail (tel: and mailto:) in flutter. Using flutter_webview_plugin

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am creating a webview app using flutter_webview_plugin. I am stack at allowing the app to launch phone call and mailto links. When I use webview_flutter I get the bottom menus and the address bar at the top does not disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to come up with this simple solution, just add these few lines of code in your initState, you can add 'mailto:' and 'sms' if necessary.

```
final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
  if (url.contains("tel:")) launch(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [the url launcher package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

const String _url = 'mailto:example@example.com';

void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: Material(
          child: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _launchURL,
              child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

void _launchURL() async {
  if (!await launch(_url)) throw 'Could not launch $_url';
}
```

Comment: The links (tel and/or mailto) are embedded within the website that will be launched using my app, so I need when call button is clicked to open call or mail

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question, please reformat your question and provide more details

Comment: Thanks Adnan. Well it's like this, I am creating a webview app using flutter_webview_plugin that will open a website which has a phone call button which when tapped from the App should allow a call to a number attached. I am stack at allowing the app to launch phone call.